# Spring Hibernate c3p0 JPA implementation throwing a no driver found error

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc, c3p0

I am trying to integration Hibernate Spring c3p0 and JPA into a production ready state. But I keep on getting this error

```
2013-02-19T07:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]: 07:55:24,556 DEBUG BasicResourcePool:1644 - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@120fe256 [managed: 0, unused: 0, excluded: 0]
2013-02-19T07:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]: 07:55:24,559 DEBUG BasicResourcePool:1831 - An exception occurred while acquiring a poolable resource. Will retry.
2013-02-19T07:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
2013-02-19T07:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:279)
2013-02-19T07:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:224)
2013-02-19T07:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:120)
2013-02-19T07:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:143)
2013-02-19T07:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:132)
2013-02-19T07:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
2013-02-19T07:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
2013-02-19T07:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
2013-02-19T07:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
2013-02-19T07:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
2013-02-19T07:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]: 07:55:24,562  WARN BasicResourcePool:1841 - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@60e1ccdf -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (1). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
2013-02-19T07:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
2013-02-19T07:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:279)
2013-02-19T07:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:224)
2013-02-19T07:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:120)
2013-02-19T07:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:143)
2013-02-19T07:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:132)
2013-02-19T07:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
2013-02-19T07:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
2013-02-19T07:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
2013-02-19T07:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
2013-02-19T07:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
2013-02-19T07:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]: 07:55:24,559 DEBUG BasicResourcePool:1831 - An exception occurred while acquiring a poolable resource. Will retry.
2013-02-19T07:55:24+00:00 app[web.1]: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
```

Here is my Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>Reservosity</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
        <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.27.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Tiles dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Junit API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- JavaMail API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javamail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javamail</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Java Activation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JavaMail extension -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.6-rc1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- LOG4J -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- The newrelic-agent.jar dependency. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.newrelic.agent.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>newrelic-agent</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- The newrelic-api.jar dependency. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.newrelic.agent.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>newrelic-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- The newrelic-java.zip dependency. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.newrelic.agent.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>newrelic-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-zip</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.newrelic.agent.java</groupId>
                                <artifactId>newrelic-java</artifactId>
                                <version>theVersion</version>
                                <type>zip</type>
                                <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                                <destFileName>newrelic</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                        <outputDirectory>/newrelic</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0.27.1</version>
                                <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

ApplicationContext.xml

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.muuves.reservosity" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<beans profile="default">
    <bean class="java.net.URI" id="dbUrl">
        <constructor-arg value="http://localhost:3306/reservosity" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/reservosity" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="toor" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">verify</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>


<beans profile="prod">
    <bean class="java.net.URI" id="dbUrl">
        <constructor-arg value="#{systemEnvironment['CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL']}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl"
            value="#{ 'jdbc:mysql://' + @dbUrl.getHost() + @dbUrl.getPath() }" />
        <property name="user" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[0] }" />
        <property name="password" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[1] }" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">verify</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">5000</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">100</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts">1</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Security-context.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<!-- <security:http auto-config='true'> -->
<security:http auto-config='true' use-expressions='true'
    once-per-request='false'>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/welcome*"
        access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/**"
        access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="https" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
        access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" requires-channel="any" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="favicon.ico"
        access="permitAll" />
    <!-- <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession"/> -->

    <!-- Make sure you are not sending login/password in plain text on open 
        channel. Use SSL (https) instead -->
    <!-- <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" requires-channel="https"/> 
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" requires-channel="https"/> 
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="http"/> form login 
        <security:form-login login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" login-page="/**" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=true" /> <security:logout 
        /> -->

    <!-- logout -->
    <!-- <security:logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"/> -->

    <!-- remember me -->
    <!-- <security:remember-me key="rememberMeKey" user-service-ref="companyServiceImpl"/> -->
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="authenticationServiceImpl" />
</security:authentication-manager>
```

META-INF/persistance.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="dataSource" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
</persistence-unit>
```

I would appreciate anyones help thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the following which fixed it yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeees

Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="dataSource">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
            <properties>
                <property key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
                <property key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
                <property key="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
                <property key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">verify</property>
                <property key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
                <property key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
                <property key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
                <property key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
                <property key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">5000</property>
                <property key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">100</property>
                <property key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
                <property key="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>
                <property key="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts">1</property>
        </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

ApplicationContext.xml

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url"
            value="#{ 'jdbc:mysql://' + @dbUrl.getHost() + @dbUrl.getPath() }" />
        <property name="username" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[0] }" />
        <property name="password" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[1] }" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```